# MapR - Rest API list command is not giving proper output

Tags: rest, hadoop, mapr

MapR REST API for MapR DB looks like not working correctly. I simply tried list command for column family as filter but it is not giving me proper output but it is perfectly working with maprcli option.Here is a list of operation that i did.

**With maprcli command**

**maprcli table cf list -path /user/hbase/testShashi**

readperm  appendperm  inmemory  versionperm  cfname  writeperm  compressionperm  memoryperm  compression  ttl         maxversions  minversions
u:mapr    u:mapr      false     u:mapr       **f1**      u:mapr     u:mapr           u:mapr      off          2147483647  1            0
u:mapr    u:mapr      false     u:mapr       **f2**      u:mapr     u:mapr           u:mapr      off          2147483647  1            0

**maprcli table cf list -path /user/hbase/testShashi -cfname f1**

readperm  appendperm  inmemory  versionperm  cfname  writeperm  compressionperm  memoryperm  compression  ttl         maxversions  minversions
u:mapr    u:mapr      false     u:mapr       **f1**      u:mapr     u:mapr           u:mapr      off          2147483647  1            0

with maprcli option when i passed cfname as f1 , it giving me only single record but it does not seems to happen with REST API

**With REST API**
Before applying filter

curl -k -u  mapr:mapr  https://hostname:8443/rest/table/cf/list?path=/user/hbase/testShashi

[image]

**with cfname as option**

curl -k -u  mapr:mapr  https://hostname:8443/rest/table/cf/list?path=/user/hbase/testShashi&cfname=f1

[image]

Let me know if I am making any mistake here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shashi,

I don't know if you pasted your exact command lines, but if you did, you probably need to add quotes around the url so that the & is not interpreted by the shell.

On MapR 4.1 this works for me:

```
[mapr@ip-172-16-2-19 ~]$ curl -k -u mapr:mapr 'https://ip-172-16-2-17:8443/rest/table/cf/list?path=/tmp/mytable&cfname=cf1' | jq .
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   345  100   345    0     0   1638      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1642
{
  "timestamp": 1436384780597,
  "timeofday": "2015-07-08 07:46:20.597 GMT+0000",
  "status": "OK",
  "total": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "cfname": "cf1",
      "maxversions": 1,
      "minversions": 0,
      "ttl": 2147483647,
      "inmemory": false,
      "compression": "lz4",
      "appendperm": "u:mapr",
      "compressionperm": "u:mapr",
      "memoryperm": "u:mapr",
      "readperm": "u:mapr",
      "versionperm": "u:mapr",
      "writeperm": "u:mapr"
    }
  ]
}
```

But if I remove the quotes as in your example, see how the cfname parameter seems to be ignored - this is because when the shell got to the &, it put the command into the background, and the cfname parameter never is considered by the server because it does not get there; and so maprcli lists all the cfs:

```
[mapr@ip-172-16-2-19 ~]$ curl -k -u mapr:mapr https://ip-172-16-2-17:8443/rest/table/cf/list?path=/tmp/mytable&cfname=cf1 | jq .
[1] 18868
[mapr@ip-172-16-2-19 ~]$ {"timestamp":1436384975909,"timeofday":"2015-07-08 07:49:35.909 GMT+0000","status":"OK","total":2,"data":[{"cfname":"cf1","maxversions":1,"minversions":0,"ttl":2147483647,"inmemory":false,"compression":"lz4","appendperm":"u:mapr","compressionperm":"u:mapr","memoryperm":"u:mapr","readperm":"u:mapr","versionperm":"u:mapr","writeperm":"u:mapr"},{"cfname":"cf2","maxversions":1,"minversions":0,"ttl":2147483647,"inmemory":false,"compression":"lz4","appendperm":"u:mapr","compressionperm":"u:mapr","memoryperm":"u:mapr","readperm":"u:mapr","versionperm":"u:mapr","writeperm":"u:mapr"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks Vig. cfname parameter is getting ignored in shell. I added quotes and it is perfectly working.